# Python try except finally

Tags: python, web2py, try-catch-finally

It looks like I don't quite have the hang of Exception handling yet. I'm at a loss :(
The following code sometimes returns this error:

```
File "applications/pingback/modules/plugin_h_pingback.py", line 190, in ping
    db(table.id==id_).update(status=status)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'status' referenced before assignment
```

I would expect `status` to always have been assigned a value. Could it be that some other exception is thrown (perhaps in the inner `try`) and the `finally` obscures it?

```
...
try:
    server_url = self._get_pingback_server(target)
except PingbackClientError, e:
    status = e.message
else:
    try:
        server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_url)
        status = server.pingback.ping(self.source, target)
    except xmlrpclib.Fault, e:
        status = e
finally:
    db(table.id==id_).update(status=status) # <-- UnboundLocalError
...
```

Thanks, HC

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your code doesn't always assign something to status. I can see a few ways that status might not be assigned and I've highlighted them below:

```
try:
    server_url = self._get_pingback_server(target)
except PingbackClientError, e:
    # If evaluating `e.message` raises an exception then status is not set.
    status = e.message  # <--- here
else:
    try:
        # If either of these two lines fails with something other than
        # xmlrcplib.Fault, then status is not set.
        server = xmlrpclib.ServerProxy(server_url)             # <--- here
        status = server.pingback.ping(self.source, target)     # <--- here
    # If xmlrpclib.Fault is not defined status is not set.
    except xmlrpclib.Fault, e:                                 # <--- here
        status = e
finally:
    db(table.id==id_).update(status=status)
```

I suspect that the most likely place for the error is in the inner try block where you are only catching `xmlrpclib.Fault` and not other types of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks Mark. So the finally effectively hides any uncaught exceptions that are raised somewhere else in the try block if it fails itself, because its block is always executed?

Comment: "Hides" in the sense of temporarily intercepting it and then forwarding it only if the finally block doesn't have its own exception to raise.

Answer (score 3):

As a simple solution, I'd initialize status outside any blocks:

```
status = None
try: 
    # etc
```

Then status will always be bound. That will not solve the problem of any unhandled exception, but it will solve the UnboundLocalError.

(Also, in the first block you assing status with e.message, in the following block, you just use the complete error e, not just the message.)